# Different jobName per Job when reporting Flink metrics to PushGateway

Tags: java, apache-flink, prometheus, metrics

I'm using Flink 1.9.1 with PrometheusPushGateway to report my metrics.
The jobName the metrics are reported with is defined in the flink-conf.yaml file which makes the jobName identical for all jobs who run on the cluster, but I want a different jobName to be reported for every running job.
To do so, I tried overriding the config's value inside the job before executing the Stream:

```java
Configuration conf = GlobalConfiguration.loadConfiguration();
    conf.setString(
            "metrics.reporter.promgateway.jobName",
            conf.getString("metrics.reporter.promgateway.jobName", "") + "-" + pipeline
    );
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(conf);
```

When `pipeline` is a String variable.

When running the job locally, it worked. But now I'm running flink in High Availability mode and it doesn't work anymore :( The config I override in the code is ignored and only the value in the cluster's flink-conf.yaml file is used.

So how can I change the jobName per job? And if I can't, is there a way to set additional Labels when reporting the metrics? Because I haven't seen an option for that as well.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following steps to achieve this:

1. Pass `jobName` as a command argument like: `--jobName MyJobName`
2. Set global parameters:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ParameterTool command = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
    String jobName = command.getRequired("jobName");

    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    Configuration globalConfiguration = new Configuration();
    globalConfiguration.setString("jobName", jobName);
    env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(globalConfiguration);

}
```

3. Use it:

```java
ParameterTool parameters = (ParameterTool) getRuntimeContext().getExecutionConfig().getGlobalJobParameters();
parameters.getRequired("jobName");
```

Here is a link that may help you too:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/best_practices.html#parsing-command-line-arguments-and-passing-them-around-in-your-flink-application

Comment: How is that different from what I did? And I'm not the one using the parameter `metrics.reporter.promgateway.jobName`. It's the written PrometheusPushGatewayReporter's `open` function.